# Is it possible that My app which is Distributable can be downloaded from my website without going to AppStore?

Tags: iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

Is it possible that if I have registered my app to Appstore. But I dont want that my app to be downloaded from AppStore. I want that it should only be downloaded from my website/Hosting.

what are the comments on this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can do it, but...

There are 2 ways:

1. You can purchase **Standard Developer Program** and distribute your app via email or hosting, but you are limited **up to 100 devices**. It's called **Ad Hoc Distribution**. Taken from [Apple's developer program overview](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html):

   > With Ad Hoc distribution you can share your application with up to 100 other iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch users. Through email or by posting it to a website or server, users can download and install your app.
2. You can purchase **Enterprise Developer Program** ($299/year) and distribute your app with **In-House Distribution**. It will be available on App Store, but only "registered" users can download them.

Comment: ok so in case of Enterprise Developer Program, do my all customers or employees need to have account with Apple. or I can have 1 account and distribute to several customers. Also I want to know that how many maximum device can be registered with 1 account??

Comment: There are no limitations, I think. Here are some docs: http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf, http://aaronparecki.com/How_to_Distribute_your_iOS_Apps_Over_the_Air

Comment: In the case of the Enterprise Developer program, you are not allowed to distribute apps to customers (unless they just happen to be your 99 Ad Hoc test device users).

Comment: No, they can be only employees of your company.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer No, you can use the ad-hoc method explained by Kashiv.

Long anser, yes with the enterprise license, but you are not allowed to distribute the to people outside of you company. If apple finds out about they could take legal actions.

Comment: ok so in case of Enterprise Developer Program, do my all customers or employees need to have account with Apple. or I can have 1 account and distribute to several customers. Also I want to know that how many maximum device can be registered with 1 account??

Comment: With the enterprise license you can distribute to unlimited device. They do not need to have any accounts. BUT IT IS NOT ALLOWED BY APPLE.

Comment: The Enterprise program is not for customers.  It is only for employees of the D&B rated enrolled corporation.

Answer (score 2):

iOS itself prohibits downloading or running apps except from Apple's App store, or from an enrolled Enterprise's App store (which is for employees of a D&B rated corporation **only**), or, for a limited time, for an enrolled iOS developer's allowed 100 **max** registered test devices, or as online source code for other enrolled iOS developers to build and run on their test devices.

This is built into the iOS security for any stock OS device.

So it does not matter what you want.  You can't do it (except with the limited exceptions mentioned above).